# Conditions on $\sigma$ to compute/bound $ I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \prod_{i=1}^{n} e^{-\tilde{\omega}_i \sigma(\omega_i x + b_i)} \, dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrices

I am investigating the following integral :

$$
I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \prod_{i=1}^{n} e^{-\tilde{\omega}_i  \sigma(\omega_i x + b_i)} \, dx
$$

**With:**

- Vector $ \tilde{\omega} $ has length $ h \in \mathbb{N}^* $.
- Matrix $ \omega $ has dimensions $ h \times d $ with $d\in \mathbb{N}^*$.
- Vector $ x $ is from $ \mathbb{R}^d $.
- $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is applied element-wise.

**Primary Questions:**

1. **Is there an activation function $ \sigma $ that renders $ I $ computable with the fewest constraints on the parameters?** By 'activation function', I refer to a nonlinear function typically used in neural network models such as ReLU, Sigmoid...
2. **If parameter constraints are necessary, what are the minimal conditions for $ \tilde{\omega} $, $ \omega $, and $ b $ that lead to a finite and computable $ I $?** For instance, is it mandatory for $ \tilde{\omega} $ to maintain a constant sign, such as $ \tilde{\omega} > 0 $?

**Secondary Interest:**

- **In the absence of a computable form, I am highly interested in obtaining any bounds (upper and lower) for $ I $  that are expressed as functions of the integral's parameters.**
- **Any strategies for bounding or computing the integral, or references to such methods in existing literature, would be particularly helpful.**

I am open to considering a restricted domain for $ x $ if it enables progress, such as constraining it to $ \mathbb{R} $ or an open interval like $ \left] -1,1 \right[ $.

Any pointers to literature that might provide a starting point or a solution, even if partial, would be gratefully received!